# How to expand/collapse groups in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder

I have a very simple report with only 4 fields. The first field is the Customer group, the parent (and only) group.

The trouble is, a lot of the Customers have many entries, so it's not easy to thumb through the report --there are a lot of pages.

The field headers are arranged in the following order:

**Customer | CreatedDate | Object | Value**

I wanted to make the Customer field/group collapsible/expandable. I would like the initial setting to have all Customer group rows collapsed at the start so the user can expand the Customer they choose.

I've tried about 4 different tutorials I found on Google and nothing's working.

Comment: have you looked at this? http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/9/19/expand-or-collapse-all-grouped-items-on-ssrs-report.html  

I don't think anyone can explain it any better here than it has been elsewhere.

Comment: Like Harry mentioned I would look into "Display can be toggled by this report item:"